# Python issue with if statement

Tags: python, json, list, if-statement

I have a massive JSON file containing titles and paragraphs of articles. What I want to do is erase any entry (title and paragraphs) who has less than 5 paragraphs and then save it to a new JSON file. I wrote the following code and every time I execute it I get 4 OKs (else branch is executing) and then it stops. I tried to print len(docs[x]) and I get the number of paragraphs each title has and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and it executed only 4 times. I suspect that something is wrong with my if statement but I cannot get it. Thanks!

```
final = []
docs = []

with open("/Users/jorjis/Desktop/Merge_stuff/merged.json") as j:
    json_data = j.read()
    data = json.loads(json_data)

for x in range(0, len(data)):
    final.append(data[x]['title'])
    docs.append(data[x]['paragraphs'])
    if len(docs[x]) < 5:
        del final[x]
        del docs[x]
    else:
        print "OK"

with open('over_five.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: each time you `del` from `docs` you are changing the indexing on it.  Try constructing the `docs` with a comprehension.

Comment: I haven't thought that this could be the problem. Cool! Any ideas of how I can fix that?

Comment: As an aside, and considering that its a massive file, read the json file directly (`data = json.load(j)`) instead of using the intermediate json_data string. The load will be faster and you won't keep the text of the file in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your logic and only append if it meets the requirement, you are running into the issue because you are changing the list you are accessing, there is no point adding the data and then removing it anyway:

```
for x in data:
    if len(x['paragraphs']) > 4: # if length is greater than 4 
        final.append(x['title']) # add the items
        docs.append(x['paragraphs'])
```

You can just iterate over data and access each element  no need for `xrange`.

You can just use `data = json.loads(j)`.